# how to delete call Log of last 24 hours android

Tags: java, android, calllog

```
public void delete() {

    String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";

    Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse(strUriCalls);

    Cursor cc = getContext().getContentResolver().query(UriCalls, null, null, null, null);

    int number = cc.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);

    int date = cc.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

    if (cc.getCount() <= 0)

    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Call log empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    while (cc.moveToNext()) {


        String callNumber = cc.getString(number);





        String callDate = cc.getString(date);
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

        try {
            systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String myDate1 = sdf.format(systemDate);


//txtCurrentTime.setText(myDate);

            cDate = sdf.format(Long.parseLong(callDate));

            Date1 = sdf.parse(myDate1);
            Date2 = sdf.parse(cDate);
//to get time diff between current date and call date 


            millse = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();
            mills = Math.abs(millse);
// to change the return value into specific time format


            long hh = (mills / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            Mins = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
            long Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;
            long timeDifDays = mills / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);



            if (timeDifDays >= 24) {

                int i = getContext().getContentResolver().delete(UriCalls, callNumber, null);

                if (i >= 1)

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Number deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No such number in call logs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    }
```

It deletes all the records of a particular number if one record satisfies the condition, I want to delete the satisfying record only.

Comment: Well all I can see is that you ask to delete in the `UriCall` the `callNumber`. You might want to get an ID of that Call log.

Comment: Using [`BaseColumns._ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID) to delete the specific row should be better. `contentResolver.delete(uri, BaseColumns._ID + " = ?", rowID);` should be better. Not sure on the syntax of those query, not done one in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void delete() {

```
String strUriCalls = "content://call_log/calls";

Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse(strUriCalls);

Cursor cc = getContext().getContentResolver().query(UriCalls, null, null, null, null);

int number = cc.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID);

int date = cc.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

if (cc.getCount() <= 0)

{
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Call log empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

while (cc.moveToNext()) {


    String callNumber = cc.getString(number);





    String callDate = cc.getString(date);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    try {
        systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String myDate1 = sdf.format(systemDate);
```

//txtCurrentTime.setText(myDate);

```
        cDate = sdf.format(Long.parseLong(callDate));

        Date1 = sdf.parse(myDate1);
        Date2 = sdf.parse(cDate);
```

//to get time diff between current date and call date

```
        millse = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();
        mills = Math.abs(millse);
```

// to change the return value into specific time format

```
        long hh = (mills / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        Mins = (int) (mills / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;
        long timeDifDays = mills / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);



        if (timeDifDays >= 24) {

            int i = getContext().getContentResolver().delete(UriCalls, BaseColumns._ID+"=?", new String[]{callNumber});

            if (i >= 1)

            {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Number deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else

            {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No such number in call logs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


}
```